# "Rendered output" doesn't render LaTeX in Review Queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, reviewing, latex

The rendered output still shows the markdown for LaTeX in the review queue:

[image: Screenshot from review queue]

[Question pictured.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37635/34718)

Comment: [Doesn't seem to be the case here...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmFmL.png) (Chrome 75.0.3770.142, Windows 10 Version 1903).

Comment: I have the same Chrome, but I'm on Windows 1803.

Comment: It seems the problem only appears when the page is loaded on the markdown tab and then switched to rendered output.

Comment: Related: [1](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25711/); [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232123/); [3](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27463/); [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128068/); [5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/321694/).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a widely known bug that doesn't appear to be something that they're planning to fix any time soon.

Comment: Since the bug seems to hit differently, here's an example that I suspect should display the problem for most viewers: [example](https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/444458/revisions).